# Java - Swapping two different types of multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, php, multidimensional-array, swap

Is it possible for me to swap one character type multidimensional array with another integer type array?
This problem was asked to me during a PHP developer interview. Since in PHP there are no data types just $ variables so I think it's possible. I wanna know if it is possible in Java.

```
int A[][]=new int[4][4];
char B[][]=new char[4][4];
A=|1234
  |5678
  |9 10 11 12
  |13 14 15 16 
B=|ABCD
  |EFGH
  |IJKL
  |MNOP

result

A=|ABCD
  |EFGH
  |IJKL
  |MNOP

B=|1234
  |5678
  |9 10 11 12
  |13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not literally possible. An integer array is an array of integers and can by definition not contain chars. You will never be able to store 'A' as an int, because it isn't.

On the other hand, it is possible to cast integers to chars and the other way around. You'll just get the number representing the char internally when you cast a char to an int and you'll get the char that is represented by the int when you cast an into to a char.

Together with casting any element you read from one of the arrays back to the type you want it to have, this could work as a hack to do what you're trying to do. I don't see why you would want it'though.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could use an array of Objects and use the wrapper classes, like Integer[] and Character[].
If you want to use real primitives, there is no way to do that, since those are copied by value, not be reference, and those values can have different sizes in memory. For example, an integer would be twice the size of a short, so you could not put it into the memory that was reserved for a smaller data type. As mentioned in S.Joshi's answer, it kind of works for integers and chars, but you would have to cast back and forth.